# spread operator in javascript with key in array

Tags: javascript, node.js

Going over this code in github https://github.com/WebDevSimplified/postman-clone, I simply do not understand below portion

```
function keyValuePairsToObjects(container) {
    const pairs = container.querySelectorAll('[data-key-value-pair]')
    return [...pairs].reduce((data, pair) => {
        const key = pair.querySelector('[data-key]').value
        const value = pair.querySelector('[data-value]').value
        if (key === '') return data
        return { ...data, [key]: value }
    }, {})
}
```

{...data, [key]: value}    Why is key inside of an array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Key is not an array, this is the syntax for using a variable name as the key, like the `obj["prop"]` syntax, `{ ["prop"]: true }` is like `{ prop: true }`.

Context for comments:

```js
> { ["prop"]: true }
{ prop: true }
> { prop: true }
{ prop: true }
```

Comment: thank you.. I was just looking at the doc and it has no information for something like this.. do I just suck at looking at document or is this a common concept from plain javascript?

Comment: If this helped, please accept the answer. Also: this is a plain JS feature.

Comment: thanks.. I am trying but it says I have to wait for 5 min before I can accept the answer. thank you.

Comment: btw, I did accept this answer, however {["prop"]: true} is NOT equal to {prop: true}

Comment: It is, unless you mean using `===`, no objects are ever equal unless they reference the same object.

Comment: when I run this code, with [] and vs none, difference is that without [], I get key:${value}    vs, when I put [], I get ${key}:${value}

Comment: you need the quotes otherwise it uses the value of key, see my edit

Comment: i was just demonstrating how if you had `let x = "foo"`, then `{ [x]: true }` is like `{ foo: true }`